# i want to create custom button for attachment of document in Accounts but when i uploaded it is giving error

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="FileToDocument">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:inputFile fileName="{!d.name}" fileSize="{!d.bodyLength}" value="{!d.body}"></apex:inputFile>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!upload}" value="Attach"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public class FileToDocument {

    public PageReference upload() {
        d.folderId='00590000000yBOm';
        insert d;
        return null;
    }

    public Document d {get;set;}
    Public FileToDocument(){
        d=new Document();
    }
}
```

Comment: public class FileToDocument {

    public PageReference upload() {
        d.folderId='00590000000yBOm';
        insert d;
        return null;
    }

    public Document d {get;set;}
    Public FileToDocument(){
        d=new Document();
    }
}

Comment: There's not enough information for us to help you. What error are you receiving?

Comment: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
Error is in expression '{!upload}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page upload: Class.FileToDocument.upload: line 9, column 1

Class.FileToDocument.upload: line 9, column 1

Answer (score 0):

If your vf page has a standard controller, your controller extesion should have a custructor which accepts `ApexPages.StandardController` type parameter. Also for insert a `Document` record `Name` is a required field.

Try this.

```
public class FileToDocument {
    public Document d {get;set;}
    Public FileToDocument(){

    }
    Public FileToDocument(ApexPages.StandardController controller){

    }
    public PageReference upload() {
        d=new Document();
        d.folderId='00590000000yBOm';
        d.Name = 'Test';
        insert d;
        return null;
    }
}
```